# How to compare Uid in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

In the below code i need to compare the uid and return the result if its true. Im new to Flutter. Please help me to learn

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('tripdetails')
                    .snapshots()
                    .where((event) => false)
```

Comment: This question barely has any information. What are you trying to compare? What is the structure of the data stored?

Comment: I have data stored in Firebase with uid and I want to compare uid and display the data.. i don't know how to put it in where clause

Comment: Still, I don't know how your data looks like on Firebase. Where is this uid variable exactly?

Can you share a sample?

Answer (score 0):

Share a screenshot of the data and adequately explain what you want to compare. That will help us to provide a proper answer.
Generally to compare uid,

in the stream, you can get the total collection data, and then inside the builder you can get the specific doc that matches the required uid.

Comment: Give one example so that i can try to do it.. i don't know how to post the more information, I will learn and do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [perform a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) on the database, that'd look something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('tripdetails')
  .where('uid', isEqualTo: 'theUidValueToFilterOn')
  .snapshots()
```